# GAE python string equality - strange behvaior with unicode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We are trying to compare strings, one is loaded from the datastore and the other is acquired from a HTML form using

```
modelID = self.request.get('fieldName')
```

Then we compare the two:

```
result = db.Query(modelName).filter('model_id =', modelID).fetch(limit=1)
```

But althout I checked the datastore viewer and clearly see that an entity exists with model_id = modelID, python insists they are not equal trampling my attempt to make my app work.

Comment: Instead of using `.fetch(limit=1)`, then having to check for a result, index it, etc, just use `.get()`, which returns None if there's no results, or the first result if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for spaces in the string

you can use the string.strip() function to get rid of them!
spaces are evil and will prevent equality...

take care man!

Answer (score 1):

Try unicode(modelID) in the filter instead of modelID.

I think GAE stores strings as unicodes.

Comment: Does this make a difference? It wouldn't make a difference in e.g. a python dict key.